# Can't get access to Data Hub Service using Java API

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I'm trying to execute a search on my Data Hub Service using Java API. Unfortunately, the server returns the `Unauthorized` response.
Here is the code:

```
  public Object doSearch() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    String user = *****;
    String password = ******;
    String db = "data-hub-FINAL";
    String host = "***********.marklogicsvc.com";
    int port = 8011;
    SecurityContext auth = new DatabaseClientFactory.DigestAuthContext(user, password).withSSLContext(SSLContext.getDefault());
    DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(host, port, db, auth);
    try {
      QueryManager qm = client.newQueryManager();
      StructuredQueryBuilder qb = qm.newStructuredQueryBuilder();
      qm.setPageLength(100);
      var query = qb.collection("listings");

      return qm.search(query, new SearchHandle());
    } finally {
      client.release();
    }
  }
```

I suspected that I've used wrong credentials but when I tried them in Visual Studio Code Marklogic Extension it worked fine, here are my VS Code settings and query:

```
    "marklogic.modulesDb": "data-hub-MODULES",
    "marklogic.host": "*******.marklogicsvc.com",
    "marklogic.password": *******,
    "marklogic.username": *******,
    "marklogic.ssl": true,
    "marklogic.port": 8011
```

query:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace cts = "http://marklogic.com/cts";

cts:search(fn:collection(("listings")), cts:and-query(()))
```

I would be very happy if you tell me what is wrong with my Java code that I can not connect to DHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from @rjrudin is correct but here is a full code snippet that should work.

```
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];                
            }
        };
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);

        return DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(
            host, port,
            new DatabaseClientFactory.BasicAuthContext(user, password).withSSLContext(sslContext, trustManager),
            DatabaseClient.ConnectionType.GATEWAY
        );
```

Note the `DatabaseClient.ConnectionType.GATEWAY` argument because you are connecting through a load balancer with DHS.

Also note that this is not validating the certificate. For a production implementation, you would want to have logic in your trust manager that would meet your security requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use a BasicAuthContext instead of a DigestAuthContext, as DHS uses basic authentication.

I am guessing your SSL configuration is fine, but just in case - I know the docs only show an SSLContext being set - http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/intro#id_31958 - but I typically pass in an X509TrustManager and also call "withSSLHostnameVerifier(DatabaseClientFactory.SSLHostnameVerifier.ANY)". You can use an impl of X509TrustManager that accepts everything for testing.

But first try a BasicAuthContext and see if that solves the problem.